# Since Thrown weapons aren't "ranged weapons" for the purpose of Archery, are they melee weapons for the purpose of Dueling?

Tags: dnd-5e

It's established in [Sage Advice](https://twitter.com/atkinsonnathanj/status/606555335378112512?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.sageadvice.eu%2F2015%2F06%2F20%2Franged-and-thrown-weapon%2F) that the fighter class feature Fighting Style: Archery only applies to weapons in the "Ranged Weapons" table, not to thrown weapons. Jeremy Crawford says:

> That's correct. A melee weapon with the thrown property is still a melee weapon when you throw it.

Does this mean that thrown weapons get the benefit of dueling? (That is, is "When you are wielding a melee weapon in one hand and no other weapons, you gain a +2 bonus to damage rolls with that weapon.")

That seems like a kind of ... odd result.

Comment: @Miniman Thanks! For some reason I didn't find that when searching.